# Python find intersection of list elements

Tags: python

I came across a question which goes like this:
Given a list of strings, find the number of letters common to ALL elements. For example

```
mylist = ['abcdde',
          'baccd',
          'eeabg']
```

Required output: `2` Since only the letters `'a'` and `'b'` are common to all elements.
My logic was to somehow use set intersection to find the common elements. But I am not able to write code that can perform this.
Can someone please help. I would also like to have any other logic which can achieve the task more efficiently (if any).
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert each string to a `set` to find the unique elements, then use `set.intersection` to find the common elements among all the sets.

```
>>> set.intersection(*(set(i) for i in mylist))
{'a', 'b'}
```

To fully answer your question, you would then use `len` to find the number of elements in that resulting set

```
>>> len(set.intersection(*(set(i) for i in mylist)))
2
```

Comment: Thanks!,,,Could you please tell what does the `*` do?

Comment: @Dev5 That is used to "unpack" the generator expression into individual arguments https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters

Comment: Ooh ok now I understood. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can divide the list into sets and find the intersection using that:

```py
sets_list = [{letter for letter in string} for string in mylist]

print(set.intersection(*sets_list))
```

Here, you first use list comprehension to construct a list of sets and then pass those sets into the `set.intersection` function will which will return the required value.

Comment: The code worked but you have some types and case problems.  this is the output: [{'d', 'c', 'e', 'b', 'a'}, {'b', 'd', 'c', 'a'}, {'b', 'a', 'g', 'e'}]
{'b', 'a'} . set_list should be sets_list and myList should be mylist

Comment: Ahh, my mistake. it's been fixed :)